# Mysql Select specific data from 2 tables base on the third table

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables

**tbl_project**

```
db_projectid  db_projectname
1              test
2              xxx
```

**tbl_activities**

```
db_id db_projectid db_category
1      1            Civil Work
2      1            Mechanical
3      1            Electrical
```

**tbl_dailypercentage**

```
db_dpid  db_aid db_projectid db_status
1         1           1        red
2         1           1    
3         2           1
```

**db_projectid** is a primary key in **tbl_project**

**db_id** is a primary key and **db_projectid** is a foreign key in **tbl_activities**

**db_dpid** is a primary key and **db_aid** is a foreign key in **tbl_dailypercentage**
I tried this query

```
select
activities.db_id,
activities.db_category as cat,
dailypercentage.db_status,
dailypercentage.db_aid,
dailypercentage.db_projectid
from tbl_activities as activities,tbl_dailypercentage as dailypercentage
where 
dailypercentage.db_projectid='$projectId'
and
activities.db_id=dailypercentage.db_aid
and 
dailypercentage.db_status='red'
```

But i Have ab error

> Undefined variable: cat

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($statusQuery)){
        $status=$row['db_status'];
        $cat=$row['cat'];
        }  
<td> <?php if($cat=="Civil Work" && $status="red"){
echo"<p style='color:$status'>".($sumcivil/$civilCount)."</p>";}
else{echo ($sumcivil/$civilCount);}?>
</td>
```

I try also many thing the left join and the right join

to have the result  i want

The Result i want is

**For Project who have an id=1**

```
category         status
civil work       red
mechanical work  
electrical work
```

**For Project who have an id=2**

```
  category         status
  civil work      
  mechanical work  
  electrical work
```

Comment: There's something you are not showing us. The error message in your question doesn't have the usual format of a MySQL error message, and your query mentions a table called `tbl_dailypercentage` that's not in your question. Is there a reference to a variable called `$cat` or `cat` somewhere in the program you're using to run this query?

Comment: O.Jones thank you for you comment i have put incorrect name of the table tbl_dailypercentage i update it my question and i put the code where i use $cat where i fetch the result of $cat from the query

Comment: I see in your code where you *use* `$cat` but not where you first set it. I guess you're setting it from the resultset from your query. You should probably take a look at that part of your code.

Comment: @O.Jones i update id my question and i put how i fetch the result

Answer (score 1):

You showed this code:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($statusQuery)){
        $status=$row['db_status'];
        $cat=$row['cat'];
}
```

If your query returns no rows, `$status` and `$cat` will never get defined.  I guess this is what went wrong. What happens if you run that query with a MySQL client like phpMyadmin?

Similarly, if your query returns more than one row,  `$status` and `$cat` will capture the values of only the last row.

It's important to work out what you want to happen with no rows and multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

Based only on the tables in your question I have put together the following schema (I've not added constraints to the foreign keys as this is just for testing).

```
create table tbl_project (
    `db_projectid` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `db_projectname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Undefined',
    PRIMARY KEY (`db_projectid`)
);

create table tbl_activities (
    `db_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `db_projectid` INT(1) NOT NULL,
    `db_category` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Undefined',
    PRIMARY KEY (`db_id`)
);
create table tbl_dailypercentage (
    `db_dpid` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `db_aid` INT(1) NOT NULL,
    `db_projectid` INT(1) NOT NULL,
    `db_status` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`db_dpid`)
);

insert into tbl_project (db_projectname) values ('Test'), ('xxx');
insert into tbl_activities (db_projectid, db_category) values ('1', 'Civil Work'), ('1', 'Mechanical'), ('1', 'Electrical');
insert into tbl_dailypercentage (db_aid, db_projectid, db_status) values
  ('1', '1', 'red'),
  ('1', '1', null),
  ('2', '1', null);


select a.db_category as cat, dp.db_status from tbl_project p
  left join tbl_activities a on p.db_projectid = a.db_projectid
  left join tbl_dailypercentage dp on dp.db_aid = a.db_id
  where p.db_projectid = 1
  group by a.db_id;
```

[image: Results]

I've had to add the `group by` into the final query as you have multiple rows in `tbl_dailypercentage` with the same `db_aid` and `db_projectid` values.

After that, you want to tweak your php code, putting the `td` stuff inside the `while` loop:

```
<?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($statusQuery)):?>
        $status=$row['db_status'];
        $cat=$row['cat'];
    <td> <?php if($cat=="Civil Work" && $status="red"){
        echo"<p style='color:$status'>".($sumcivil/$civilCount)."</p>";}
        else{echo ($sumcivil/$civilCount);}?>
    </td>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```